# Merge two dates series into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, graph, dygraphs

I need to do some chart in Dygraph.js, with multiple series.

For example i have this dataset:

```
array1 = [ ['2016-03-16', 10,]
           ['2016-03-17', 20,]
           ['2016-03-19', 20,]
           ['2016-03-20', 15,]
         ];

array2 = [ ['2016-03-16', 30,]
           ['2016-03-18', 50,]
           ['2016-03-20', 30,]
         ];
```

And i want to merge this arrays into one:

```
merged = [ ['2016-03-16', 10, 30]
           ['2016-03-17', 20, null]
           ['2016-03-18', null, 50]
           ['2016-03-19', 20, null]
           ['2016-03-20', 15, 30,]
         ];
```

Ofcorse dates are in more complex format:  `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`.
I'm using moment.js for dates operation.

How to merge these arrays in the fastest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for any count of series.

```js
var array1 = [['2016-03-16', 10], ['2016-03-17', 20], ['2016-03-19', 20], ['2016-03-20', 15]],
    array2 = [['2016-03-16', 30], ['2016-03-18', 50], ['2016-03-20', 30]],
    merged = function (array) {
        var o = {}, r = [];
        array.forEach(function (a, i) {
            a.forEach(function (b) {
                if (!o[b[0]]) {
                    o[b[0]] = Array.apply(null, { length: array.length + 1}).map(function () { return null; });
                    o[b[0]][0] = b[0];
                    r.push(o[b[0]]);
                }
                o[b[0]][i + 1] = b[1];
            });
        });
        return r.sort(function (a, b) { return a[0].localeCompare(b[0]); });
    }([array1, array2]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(merged, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I thinks it's working but not perfect. Sometimes it doesnt't write null. http://postimg.org/image/d7cekulnv/

Comment: Now is undefined instead of null

Comment: @snuuve, now all items are initialized with `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
array1 = [ ['2016-03-16', 10,],
           ['2016-03-17', 20,],
           ['2016-03-19', 20,],
           ['2016-03-20', 15,]
         ];

array2 = [ ['2016-03-16', 30,],
           ['2016-03-18', 50,],
           ['2016-03-20', 30,]
         ];

//get the bigger array
var src = array1.length > array2.length ? array1 : array2;
//get the smaller array
var dest = array1.length > array2.length ? array2 : array1;
//iterate the bigger array
var final = src.map(function(array){
    var date = array[0];
    //find in smaller array
    var filtered = dest.filter(function(d){
        return d[0] == date;
    });
    var thirdData= null;
    if (filtered.length > 0){
      //iff filtered get the first record
        thirdData = filtered[0][1]
    }
    return [date, array[1], thirdData]
})
console.log(final);
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/b3k3qw90/)

Comment: Works for 2 arrays. What if there is more?